# ANDROID - Frame By Frame animation

Tags: android, animation

I am android beginner. I need to implement frame by frame animation in app but hows it done I didn't know please give me complete example of Frame By Frame animation.

Comment: you can check  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html and https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/frame-animations-in-android/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi you can do this by this step.

> Step 1 : Insert images in drawable folder which need for framing.
>
> Step 2 : Create an xml for configure for FrameByFrame animation and place it into res/drawable folder.
> Here there are two images are use for animation is f1 and f2.
> android:duration defines time in milisecond for change frame.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="false" >
   <item
       android:drawable="@drawable/f1"
       android:duration="50"/>
   <item
       android:drawable="@drawable/f2"
       android:duration="50"/>
</animation-list>
```

> Step 3 : Create main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/imageView1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

> Step 4 : Finally execute in MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ImageView iv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       // Imageview in which images load one by one like Frame By Frame
       iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
       //Bind xml which is configure animation.
       AnimationDrawable ad = (AnimationDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.sam);
       iv.setBackgroundDrawable(ad);
       //Start animation
       ad.start();
       //For stop animation you can use ad.stop();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

2 ways which I could think of right now are:

1. Try creating an animation-list of drawables and using them
2. Try drawing the frames using the canvas on Android